# Python main function dealing with true and false

Tags: python, function, program-entry-point

So this is my homework but I don't really know how to do one step.On the last step in the `main()` function I'm suppose to report if the number is a palindrome or not depending on the value returned by the isPalindrome function. I don't really know how to do this so can you guys please help. Thanks

This is what I got so far.

```
# Write code that reverses the number and then returns the reversed number. 

def reverse(number):
     reverse=0
     while number>0:
        reverse = reverse * 10 + number % 10
        number=number//10
        return reverse

#Write code that call the reverse function,processes the value returned by the reverse function and returns True if the number is a palindrome.It will return False if number is not a palindrome.

def isPalindrome(number):
    if number == reverse:
        return True
    else:
        return False

#Write code to prompt the user to enter an integer, calls the isPalindrome function and (depending on the value returned by the isPalindrome function) reports if the number is a palindrome or not.

def main():
    number=int(input("enter number: "))

main()
```

So I'm basically stuck on the last part

Comment: Well what's wrong? You want to call `isPalindrome` on your `number` variable, and check if it returns `True` or `False`, and inform the user accordingly, right?

Comment: call `ispalindrome` function in main and print the returned status

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention the output should come out like this 
Sample Output
Enter a number : 222
The number is a palindrome.

Another Sample Output:
Enter a number : 456
The number is not a palindrome.

Comment: You're exiting the while loop too soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `reverse` function must be like this

```
def reverse(number):
     reverse=''
     while number>0:
        reverse = reverse + str(number % 10)
        number=number//10
     return reverse
```

and in `isPalindrome` you have to compare string because `50` will be `05` and if you convert it in integer then it will be `5` only and you cant compare `50` and `5`.

```
def isPalindrome(number):
    if str(number) == reverse(number):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Then your function will work.

Comment: It did thank you so much. Thank to everyone else who answer this as well. You guys answer it really fast :)

Answer (score 1):

To call a function in Python, write the name of the function and add opening and closing parenthesis. If the function takes any arguments, add the arguments in the parenthesis. To save the return value, assign the function call to a variable (called a *name* in Python).

For example:

```
def foo(user):
   return 'Hello %s' % user

result = foo('Jett')
print result
```

The above will print `Hello Jett` when executed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you *call* your`reverse` function!

```
def is_palindrome(number):
    return number == reverse(number)
```

In `main` you should have something like this:

```
def main():
    number = int(input("enter number: "))
    if is_palindrome(number):
        print(...)   # Fill in the dots
    else:
        print(...)   # Fill in the dots
```